# SFINAE error in a trait to find the return type of any callable

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, sfinae

I am playing around with SFINAE and trying, as an exercise, to get information about "function-like" objects (functions, function pointers, lambdas, and anything overloading the parenthesis operator). I've stripped my code down to the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Callable, typename = void>
struct function_type_info;

template<typename R, typename G, typename... T>
struct function_type_info<R(G::*)(T...)> {
    using return_type = R;
};

template<typename C>
struct function_type_info<C, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, C>::type> {
    using return_type = typename function_type_info<decltype(&C::operator())>::return_type;
};

struct Callback {
    int operator()(double, std::string) {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto b = [](double, std::string) -> int { return 0; };
    auto c = Callback{};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(&Callback::operator())>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(b)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(c)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me the following errors:

```
<source>:32:64: error: incomplete type 'function_type_info<main(int, char**)::<lambda(double, std::string)> >' used in nested name specifier
   32 |     std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(b)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
      |                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:32:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   32 |     std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(b)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
      |                                                                                ^
<source>:33:64: error: incomplete type 'function_type_info<Callback>' used in nested name specifier
   33 |     std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(c)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
      |                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:33:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   33 |     std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(c)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
```

I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error. With lambdas and Callback objects, the second specialization of `function_type_info` should be accepted: `std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value` is false, so `!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value` is true, so `std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, C>::type` should evaluate to `C` and the template deduction should succeed.

If I change `std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, C>::type` into `std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type` then is works for `Callback`, but not for lambdas. Again, I'm at a loss as to why this change makes it work for `Callback` in the first place, and why, if it works for `Callbacks`, it doesn't for lambdas. The error for lambdas is the following:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct function_type_info<main(int, char**)::<lambda(double, std::string)> >':
<source>:32:62:   required from here
<source>:16:11: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct function_type_info<int (main(int, char**)::<lambda(double, std::string)>::*)(double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>) const, void>'
   16 |     using return_type = typename function_type_info<decltype(&C::operator())>::return_type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:8: note: declaration of 'struct function_type_info<int (main(int, char**)::<lambda(double, std::string)>::*)(double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>) const, void>'
    7 | struct function_type_info;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:32:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   32 |     std::cout << std::is_same<function_type_info<decltype(b)>::return_type, int>::value << std::endl;
```

It's as if I was not allowed to refer to the lambda's parenthesis operator...

Note: I know I can get return type information through other ways (`std::result_of`/`std::invoke_result`), but as I said, I'm doing this as an exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two separate problems in your code. [Here is a working version](https://godbolt.org/z/sjPneGEdv).

#### Problem A

The primary template uses

```cpp
template<typename Callable, typename = void>
struct function_type_info;
```

The specialization is defined as:

```cpp
template<typename C>
struct function_type_info<C, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, C>::type> {
    using return_type = typename function_type_info<decltype(&C::operator())>::return_type;
};
```

The mistake is providing `C` as the second template argument to `std::enable_if`.
You only ever use specializations of `function_type_info` where the second parameter is `void`, not `C`.

To fix this, write:

```cpp
std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>
// or simply
std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value>
```

#### Problem B

The call operator of lambda expressions is `const` by default, so you need another specialization to cover that:

```cpp
template<typename R, typename G, typename... T>
struct function_type_info<R(G::*)(T...) const, void> {
    using return_type = R;
};
```

Then, define 46 more partial specializations to cover all combinations of `const`, `volatile`, `noexcept`, ref-qualifiers, and variadic arguments.

Here is a compact version:

```cpp
template<typename>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits;
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A...);using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A...)noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A...)const;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A...)const noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)volatile>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)volatile;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)volatile noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)volatile noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const volatile>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)const volatile;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const volatile noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)const volatile noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A...)&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A...)&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A...)const&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A...)const&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)volatile&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)volatile&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)volatile&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)volatile&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const volatile&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)const volatile&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const volatile&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A...)const volatile&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&&;using function_type=R(A...)&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&&;using function_type=R(A...)&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&&;using function_type=R(A...)const&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&&;using function_type=R(A...)const&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)volatile&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A...)volatile&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)volatile&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A...)volatile&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const volatile&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A...)const volatile&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A...)const volatile&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=false;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A...)const volatile&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A......);using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A......)noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A......)const;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A......)const noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)volatile>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)volatile;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)volatile noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)volatile noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const volatile>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)const volatile;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const volatile noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)const volatile noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A......)&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&;using function_type=R(A......)&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A......)const&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&;using function_type=R(A......)const&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)volatile&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)volatile&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)volatile&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)volatile&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const volatile&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)const volatile&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const volatile&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&;using function_type=R(A......)const volatile&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&&;using function_type=R(A......)&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=S&&;using function_type=R(A......)&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&&;using function_type=R(A......)const&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const S&&;using function_type=R(A......)const&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)volatile&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A......)volatile&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)volatile&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A......)volatile&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const volatile&&>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A......)const volatile&&;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
template<typename R,typename S,typename...A>struct pointer_to_member_function_traits<R(S::*)(A......)const volatile&&noexcept>{constexpr static bool is_variadic=true;using class_type=S;using reference_type=const volatile S&&;using function_type=R(A......)const volatile&&noexcept;using return_type=R;using argument_types=std::tuple<A...>;};
```

Or use [this code from wreien/lazy-query](https://github.com/wreien/lazy-query/blob/master/lazy_query.hpp#L404-L456), which is slightly less insane because it uses macros to generate these 48 combinations.

This is obviously half-serious.
It just demonstrates why it's a bit silly to get the return type directly from the member function pointer type instead of using `std::invoke_result`.

Comment: Ahhh the `const` is what I was missing, plus all the possible l/r-values, volatile, noexcept, etc. combintions. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the role of `is_variadic` in your compact version? as well as the double expansion (`......`)? I'm having a hard time picture what it would match with.

Comment: @sunmat `is_variadic` is for C variadics, like `printf`. `......` is equivalent to `..., ...`. The first `...` is for the function parameter pack, the second `...` is for the C variadics.